# Eye model's cornea shader is suddenly black instead of glass

Tags: modeling, shaders, shader-nodes

I can't for the life of me figure out what went wrong and why my eye model suddenly turned dark when rendered. I'm using a glass shader for the cornea and it used to be see-through and work perfectly. Notice that the eye is beneath when you remove the faces from the cornea. I remember I had this problem before but I never was able to understand what makes it suddenly turn black. The shader for the cornea is just a simple *Glass BSDF*. Nothing more.

[image]

[image]

[Here is my eye model that actually works](https://hkunz.gumroad.com/l/ttbcd) and is supposedly the same thing. The only difference is that I joined the 2 meshes in the non-working eye model, but this used to work. I just did something like applied the scale while it was still linked to another eye object. I'm not sure.

If I append the defective eye model to the working eye model's file, then it displays correctly. Why?

Comment: It's just casting shadows way stronger than it ought to.  You can enable caustics to fix it.  (Or, mix with transparency on the basis of light paths/is shadow ray.)  Difference between append and original is going to be in the rendering settings (like caustics.)

Comment: @Nathan hey thank you for looking into this! At exactly this moment I also realized I turned off caustics because I remember Blender Guru mentioned to disable caustics to render faster now I realize that caused it and I need it else yes as you mentioned I would need to mix transparency shader. Thank you very much!